# How to write an AZDO query that returns a list bugs in one epic only?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, epic

I'm looking to get a list of bugs that exist within one epic. It's okay if it's a bit noisy, or even in multiple queries, as for my purpose I can export it and clean it up. Now, I am able to do this with a tree of work items search but I only see bugs that are children of features, but no lower. The problem in this epic I am querying is that from feature-> user-story -> task there are bugs that are children at each layer, and I need to see them all.

When I try and do a flat of work items query, I can return all bugs but for the entire project but don't know how to filter it to just the ones in one epic hierarchy, without returning to my first problem of only getting bugs that a children of features, but no lower.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps does not support such queries... but.. as a workaround, you may `match linked work items first` and filter by ID on the parent level.... in this case, you receive all work items and the tree for your particular epic:

[image]

Additionally, it`s recommended to register bugs only on one level (user story or requirements level) and consider using the Area Path to have more useful filters.